# AsyncTask DoInBackGround Return Type

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I know that in Java you can specify the return type of the DoInBackground override of the AsyncTask class, but in MonoDroid it seems to only allow the Object return type.  What if I want it to return a just a plain ole' string for use in handling the OnPostExecute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since `String` extends `Object`, you could return a `String` and then cast the return when you receive it.

```
public Object a() {

    return "this";
}

public void b() {

    Log.e((String)a(),(String)a());

}
```

This compiles and runs